# Changing a product of sums to sum of products

Tags: summation, products

Suppose we have a finite set $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$.

Let $A_i\subset A$, $i\in\{1,2\cdots,m\}$ be given.

What I want to find is how to change the order of products and summations of the following expression:

$$\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{a\in A_i}a.$$

I could find an expression when $A_i$'s have the same number of elements, $|A_i|=|A_j|,~\forall i,j$. However, in general, how can convert the above summations and products and express it in the form of $\sum\prod b_k?$

Comment: Can you do it for the case $m=2$?

Comment: Incidentally, the tag linear-algebra looks wrong. You can't have a product of multiple vectors in a vector space. direct-sum doesn't seem particularly helpful either.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the title

Comment: In a sense it is obvious how to get a sum of products - just expand using the distributive laws. So is your question really about notation, ie how to express the result neatly using a sum sign followed by a product sign?

Comment: Yes. I'm wondering if there's any neat way to express the possibly lengthy sums of products using some simple notations..

Comment: What about $$\sum_{b_i\in A_i\text{ for each }i}\prod_{j=1}^m b_j$$